# Proof or disproof Ω(n) = ω(n) U Θ(n)

Tags: big-o

Is Ω(n) = ω(n) ∪ Θ(n) true or false? How can I prove it?

I've already tried using the definitions of Ω(n), ω(n) and Θ(n) and to me it seems to be naturally true.
Its like proving that {1,2,3} = {1,2} U {3}.. how can I prove such thing?
I've also tried something like this: If a function is in Ω(n), then it should be in both ω and Θ. But this lead me to a false answer... I really can't figure this out.
In the end Ω is composed of ω and Θ. Right?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your function with the formal definitions and simplify until only axioms remain,then it will be proven.

For **big omega**:

[image]

you have the formal definition:

[image]

For **small omega**:

[image]

you have the formal definition:

[image]

and for **big theta**:

[image]

you have the formal definition:

[image]

[image]

More information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations)

Comment: I have already wrote the formal definitions, but the i have issues proving the fact that the initial statement it's true...

Comment: After few hours of debatea with a friend we solved it out. We found a function which contradicts the hipothesis. For f(n) = n + x*abs(sin(n)) there is a contradiction. f is included in big-omega(n), but if you do the graphic for the function, it will be sometimes in theta(n) and sometimes in small-omega(n) so the initial relation is proved to be false.